# TCP Proxy with multiple clients?

Tags: proxy, tcp

I am looking for a TCP proxy - a utility that will connect to a port, read a TCP stream, and write it to clients that connect to it.

The key point here is that there may be more than one client, and each client should receive a copy of the stream.

Preferably windows solution, but Linux can be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it by using **iptables** . of course you won't have the "control" that you 'd have if you deploy it in higher level. But it's still a quick and dirty solution :>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe socat? (http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)

Have a dig around in the examples (http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES)

socat -u TCP4:source.example.com:123 TCP4-LISTEN:3334,reuseaddr,fork

Warning: untested!

Comment: For socat, perhaps my [Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362423/35946) helps in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Any SOCKS proxy will do -- on Linux, have a look at a [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/) proxy or [tinyproxy](https://www.banu.com/tinyproxy/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you are looking for some type of TCP based queueing or streaming service  a pub/sub type thing.

Are you looking for something semantically similar to, say, an internet radio repeater? (where on stream comes in, and anyone else connecting joins into the live stream)

Comment: yes, that's a good way to put it.